# Need to add quickblox Q-municate in native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox, q-municate

I need to add video call ,Voice call ,Chat by using quickblox i have found Q-municate for iOS and its work perfectly.But i want to use Q-municate in my application.is it possible please help me if its possible.